# C# Decimal To Octal

Tags: c#, decimal, octal

There have been many questions but i can't seem to find the why in the answers. It's usually: no, replace this with this or this should work.

My task is to create a program that asks the user to input a 3 digit positive integer (decimal) that converts it to octal.

For example, on paper: To convert the number 112 to octal. (8 is the base number for octal.)

These are the steps you would take:

- 112 / 8 = 14 remainder = 0
- 14 / 8 = 1 remainder = 6
- 1 / 8 = 0 remainder = 1

Remainder from bottom to up is the octal number that represents 112 in decimal.
So the octal number for 112 is 160.

I found the following program on the internet but i don't understand it fully.
The comments in the program are mine. Could anyone explain it to me please?

```
        //declaration and initialization of variables but why is there an array?
        int decimalNumber, quotient, i = 1, j;
        int[] octalNumber = new int[100];

        //input
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a Decimal Number :");
        decimalNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        quotient = decimalNumber;

        //as long as quotient is not equal to 0, statement will run
        while (quotient != 0)
        {
            //this is how the remainder is calculated but it is then put in an array + 1, i don't understand this.
            octalNumber[i++] = quotient % 8;
            //divide the number given by the user with the octal base number
            quotient = quotient / 8;
        }
        Console.Write("Equivalent Octal Number is ");
        //i don't understand the code below here aswell. 
        for (j = i - 1; j > 0; j--)
            Console.Write(octalNumber[j]);
        Console.Read();
```

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't `Convert.ToString(decimalNumber, 8)` good enough?

Comment: There is an array because each octal digit is being stored in one position.  At the end, the numbers stored in the array are being written in reverse order to the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is already built into .NET, [Convert.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14kwkz77(v=vs.110).aspx) already does this.

In your code, just after you have `decimalNumber = int.Parse(...)` you can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(decimalNumber, 8));
Console.Read();
```

and then remove the rest of the code.

Now, if you're not asking how to do octal conversion in .NET but actually how that code works, here's how it works:

This loop does the heavy lifting:

```
1   while (quotient != 0)
    {
        //this is how the remainder is calculated but it is then put in an array + 1, i don't understand this.
2       octalNumber[i++] = quotient % 8;
        //divide the number given by the user with the octal base number
3       quotient = quotient / 8;
    }
```

I added some numbers to the lines to make it easier writing a description.

Basically, the loop does this (lines above correspond to points below).

1. As long as we have a number to convert (ie. we're still not done), loop.
2. Figure out the least significant digit, this is the remainder after dividing by 8, which is handled by the [remainder operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/modulus-operator), `%`, store this digit into the array in the next position.
3. Divide by 8 to get rid of that least significant digit and move all the other digits one up

Then loop back.

However, since we essentially found all the digits from the rightmost side towards the left, the loop at the end writes them back out in their opposite order.

As an exercise to the reader, try to figure out how the code in the question behaves if you:

- Input a negative number
- Input 0

*(hint, it doesn't behave correctly but Convert.ToString does)*

Comment: See `My task...` part in the post :)

Comment: That eliminates half of the code. That's a lot easier to read, easier to understand. Why the programmer made the program so complicated when it could be done with 1 line is something i don't understand. And no, i'm just practicing ;)

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov And that task is solved perfectly using `Convert.ToString`, if the task is "I have to write all the code myself as part of homework" then that is a different question.

Comment: I note that `%` is the remainder operator, not the modulus operator.

Comment: Yes, well, that is probably a point you should take up with Microsoft since they have documented it as both :) I agree completely though but I'm not going to go into such a discussion here, since Microsoft has named it the modulus operator [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/) and documented that it calculates the remainder [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/modulus-operator). And yes, I know full and well that those are different things.

Comment: Oh, believe me, I have expressed strong opinions to the documentation team on their willingness to *make up crazy stuff* in the C# documentation MANY TIMES.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing to understand is: **this is a terrible way to solve this problem.** The code is full of odd choices; it looks like someone took a bad C solution of this problem and translated it to C# without applying careful thought or using good practices.  If you are trying to learn how to understand crappy code you find on the internet, this is a great example. If you are trying to learn how to design good code, this is a great example of what not to do.

```
//declaration and initialization of variables but why is there an array?
```

There's an array because we wish to store all the octal digits, and an array is a convenient mechanism for storing a number of data of the same type.

But we could ask some more pertinent questions here:

- Why of size 100?  It's not wrong, but that's enormously larger than necessary. What thought process led to 100 being chosen? Why wasn't that thought process documented anywhere?
- Why an array of int? We're outputting text, which is a sequence of chars. It would seem more natural to have a bunch of chars.
- Why an array? Since we are building a first-in-last-out data structure, a stack seems more appropriate. Or why not simply accumulate a string? That's inefficient if the string is large, but an octal string from a 32 bit integer is never large!
- Why does the program produce output to the console? Surely a better factored program would have a method that takes an int and returns an octal string, which can then be printed.
- Why do some of the variables have descriptive names and some have undescriptive names?  Is the author of the code deliberately trying to confuse the reader? Or did they simply not think about it very carefully?
- Why does `i` - apparently the current index into the array -- start at one?!  This is simply bizarre. Arrays start at zero in C#.
- What happens if you type in a negative number?  Try it!
- What happens if you type in zero?

We then go on to:

```
decimalNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

This code presumes that the typed-in text is a legal integer, which is not guaranteed. So this program can crash.  `TryParse` should be used, and the failure mode should be handled.

```
 // this is how the remainder is calculated but it is 
 // then put in an array + 1, i don't understand this.
 octalNumber[i++] = quotient % 8;
```

The author of the code thinks they are being clever. This is too much cleverness.  Rewrite the code in your head to how it should have been implemented in the first place. First, rename `i` to `currentIndex`. Next, produce *one* side effect per statement, not *two*:

```
    while (quotient != 0)
    {
        octalNumber[currentIndex] = quotient % 8;
        currentIndex += 1;
        quotient = quotient / 8;
    }
```

Now it should be clear what is going on.

```
 // I don't understand the code below here as well. 
 for (j = i - 1; j > 0; j--)
   Console.Write(octalNumber[j]);
```

Do a little example.  Suppose the number is 14, which is 16 in octal.  First time through the loop we put 6 in slot 1.  Next time through, we put 1 in slot 2. So the array is `{0, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ... }` and `i` is 3.  We wish to output `16`.  So we loop j from i-1 to 1, and print out 1 then 6.

So, exercise for you:  **write this program again, this time using the conventions of a well-designed C# program**. Put your attempt on the code review site and people will be happy to give you tips on how to improve it.

Comment: "produce one side effect per statement". Don't you actually mean "produce no side effects", since it would actually be an effect rather than a side effect because it's what you want? Please don't hate me! ;-)

Comment: Good point. Its not a side effect if it is the intended effect!

Comment: I always thought that the data stored in an array is chronological. Like in the above example that it would be: {0, 1, 6, 0, 0, .. }.  And thank you for the great explanation. It makes total sense.

Comment: @IliasJoels: An array is simply a device which takes an *index* and produces a *variable* corresponding to that index upon demand.  So `new int[100]` produces a collection of 10 variables, with indices from 0 through 9.

Comment: @EricLippert I think there's a typo in your sentence. But what's an order of magnitude among friends? ;)

Comment: Whoops! Yes, typo.

Answer (score 0):

An array is used because they are calculating each digit every interation of the while loop. (e.g.) {0, 6, 1}

The last part of the program is printing each digit out, starting with the last item in the array and moving to the first. in this case it would print out:
160