# How to convert base 10 negative number to base 8 conversion without using Convert.To() method?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, type-conversion, base-conversion

How can i represent decimal negative number in octal without using `Convert.To()` method?

```
public static string GetOctal(int number)
{     
   int base = 8;    
}
```

So for example :

> -3 (base 10) = 37777777775 (base 8)

But what algorithm should i use to get this result?

The are test cases for my task:

```
        [TestCase(-3, 8, ExpectedResult = "37777777775")]
        [TestCase(-127, 8, ExpectedResult = "37777777601")]
        [TestCase(-675432, 8, ExpectedResult = "37775330630")]
        [TestCase(-1908345, 8, ExpectedResult = "37770560607")]
        [TestCase(int.MinValue, 8, ExpectedResult = "20000000000")]
        [TestCase(-3, 16, ExpectedResult = "FFFFFFFD")]
        [TestCase(-127, 16, ExpectedResult = "FFFFFF81")]
        [TestCase(-675432, 16, ExpectedResult = "FFF5B198")]
        [TestCase(-1908345, 16, ExpectedResult = "FFE2E187")]
        [TestCase(int.MinValue, 16, ExpectedResult = "80000000")]
        [TestCase(1908345, 10, ExpectedResult = "1908345")]
        [TestCase(int.MaxValue, 10, ExpectedResult = "2147483647")]
        public string GetRadix_Tests(int number, int radix) => number.GetRadix(radix);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Decimal To Octal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741509/c-sharp-decimal-to-octal)

Comment: `37777777775`(octal) is not negative (this would be `-3` also in octal). So probably this is `(uint)number` converted.

Comment: @Klaus Gütter Please, watch the test-cases which i added

Comment: @Fabjan No, because there are no algorithm to convert signed negative numbers.

Comment: @AliaksandrAfiarouski also according to the test cases, it seems that the expected outcome is to convert `(uint)number` to the given base. So the conversion itself does not have to handle negative numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always go the source code of the `Convert` class at source.dot.net [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Convert.cs,2283) and follow `ParseNumber`'s `IntToString` method:

> ```
> public static string IntToString(int n, int radix, int width, char paddingChar, int flags)
> {
>     Span<char> buffer = stackalloc char[66]; // Longest possible string length for an integer in binary notation with prefix
>
>     if (radix < MinRadix || radix > MaxRadix)
>         throw new ArgumentException(SR.Arg_InvalidBase, nameof(radix));
>
>     // If the number is negative, make it positive and remember the sign.
>     // If the number is MIN_VALUE, this will still be negative, so we'll have to
>     // special case this later.
>     bool isNegative = false;
>     uint l;
>     if (n < 0)
>     {
>         isNegative = true;
>     (...)
> ```